# How can I send an email with the email inside of an array? with smptlib on python

Tags: python, arrays, list, automation

I'm new here in StackOverFlow,intermediate python student, and I coded an script to send my homeworks 90% automatically, but **it isn't going inside try function to send the email**, I think the code isn't understanding the array, I used some mime/email lib and smptlib, my biggest difficult its to send the email with the emails in an array, I want to take the email inside of the array[subject] but it didn't worked (my discord is > gOld#3140):

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders
import mimetypes

class web():
    def __init__(self):

        # Criando as vars necessárias
        from_email = input('Write your email: ')
        password = input('Write your email password: ')
        subject_matter = input('Write the email subject matter: ')
        filedir = input('Write the dir of the archive to attach: ')

        # Setting up the email layout

        msg = MIMEMultipart()
        msg['From'] = from_email
        msg['Subject'] = subject_matter

        message = (f"""
        Hello, here are the drive homeworks:

        """)    # Edit this ^
                #           i

        msg.attach(MIMEText(message))

        attachment = open(filedir, "rb")

        mime_attach = mimetypes.guess_type(filedir)[0].split('/')

        part = MIMEBase(mime_attach[0], mime_attach[1])
        part.set_payload((attachment).read())
        encoders.encode_base64(part)
        part.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" % filedir)
        msg_text = MIMEText(message, 'html')
        msg.attach(part)

        # Trying to send:


        filename2 = filedir.split("/")[-1].split(".")[0]

        subjects_mails = {
            'sociology': '@gmail.com',
            'biology': '@gmail.com',
            'geography': '@gmail.com',
            'mathematics': '@gmail.com',
            'science': '@gmail.com',
            'philosophy': '@gmail.com',
            'physical_education': '@gmail.com',
            'history': '@gmail.com',
            'portuguese': '@gmail.com',
            'informatic': '@gmail.com',
            'physics': '@gmail.com',
            'chemical': '@gmail.com',
            'life_project': '@gmail.com',
        }

        subject = input('Write your subject that you wanna to send an email: ')
        subject_recmail = ''

        for subject in subjects_mails.keys():
            if subject == subjects_mails and filename2 == subject:
                try:
                    subject_recmail = subjects_mails.get(subject)
                    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
                    server.ehlo()
                    server.starttls()
                    server.ehlo()
                    server.login(from_email, password)
                    server.sendmail(from_email, subject_recmail, msg.as_string())        
                   print("Email has been sent to ", subject_recmail)
                   server.quit()
                except Exception as err:
                    print(err)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    works = web()
```

[Code ran > image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOuhV.jpg)

Comment: There is no array here. Do you mean you want to attach all the files from the directory? You should probably switch from this old-fashioned legacy `email` style to the modern Python 3.6+ `EmailMessage` API.

Comment: Calling your email class `web` is quite curious. SMTP email predates the World Wide Web by some 15+ years and uses a completely different set of protocols.

Comment: I'm student of python guys, idk all, if you can help me writing the code....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem is with the line

```
if subject == subjects_mails and filename2 == subject:
```

You're making a comparison between subject (a key) and subjects_mails (a dictionary), so these things will never be equal under the "==" operator.

Comment: Can you write the code that is the right type?

Comment: The problem is, you overwrote the namespace. You used the same variable name twice.In the For loop, you could switch it to: for key in subjects_mails.keys(): if subject == key. But then you're also comparing subject to filename2, which I do not understand.

Comment: I will try your suggestion now, and I comeback to give you the feedback, if you wanna talk me better, my discord is: gOld#3140.

Comment: yes man, I changed the for and the if, and it works, I appreciate so much your help dave.

Answer (score 0):

[User that helped me](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14055259/davetherock)

The problem was inside the for function and the if, I changed it to:

```
for key in subjects_mail.keys():
    if key == subject:
        try:
            subject_recmail = subjects_mails.get(subject)
            server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
            server.ehlo()
            server.starttls()
            server.ehlo()
            server.login(from_email, password)
            server.sendmail(from_email, subject_recmail, msg.as_string())        
            print("Email has been sent to ", subject_recmail)
            server.quit()
        except Exception as err:
            print(err)
```